# How to catch Key Vault SecretClient errors Azure Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure-keyvault, try-except, azure-sdk-python

I'm new to Python. I have a working monolithic program that I'd like to break into individual functions (`def`) using `try:` - `except:` to handle errors.

What are some methods for catching errors in the creation of a Key Vault `SecretClient`?

**Attempt 1:**

- Nothing happens here when I put in a bad `kv_name`.
- I'd expect it to log the `except:` message specified.

```
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()

def create_kv_client(kv_name, credentials):
    try:
        kv_uri = 'https://' + kv_name + '.vault.azure.net'
        kv_client = SecretClient(vault_url=kv_uri, credential=credentials)
    except:
        logging.error('####### Failed to create Key Vault Client #######')
    return kv_client

kv_client = create_kv_client('notmykeyvaultname', credentials)
```

**Attempt 2:**

- Nothing happens here either when I put in a bad `kv_name`
- I'd expect it to raise an error.

```
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()

def create_kv_client(kv_name, credentials):
    try:
        kv_uri = 'https://' + kv_name + '.vault.azure.net'
        kv_client = SecretClient(vault_url=kv_uri, credential=credentials)
    except:
        logging.error('####### Failed to create Key Vault Client #######')
    return kv_client

kv_client = create_kv_client('notmykeyvaultname', credentials)

if kv_client == None:
    raise Exception('Failed to create Key Vault Client')
```

**Attempt 3:**

- Moving the `try:` - `except:` to the function call did not trigger the logging message either
- I'd expect the `SecretClient` to fail here!?

```
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()

def create_kv_client(kv_name, credentials):
    kv_uri = 'https://' + kv_name + '.vault.azure.net'
    kv_client = SecretClient(vault_url=kv_uri, credential=credentials)
    return kv_client

try:
    kv_client = create_kv_client('notmykeyvaultname', credentials)
except:
    logging.info('####### Failed to create Key Vault client #######')
```

**Sanity check:**

- When I run the commands *outside* the function, the output of a failed `SecretClient` is not `None`.
- What can I hook into here to determine if `SecretClient` was successfully created?

```
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()

kv_uri = 'https://' + 'notmykeyvaultname' + '.vault.azure.net'

kv_client = SecretClient(vault_url=kv_uri, credential=credentials)

kv_client

`<azure.keyvault.secrets._client.SecretClient at 0x1512046b370>`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructor doesn't check whether the given vault exists, or whether you can access it, so in your attempts it succeeds: you get a `SecretClient` instance, no error raised.

If the URL is that of a nonexistent vault, or a vault you aren't authorized to access, you'll see an error when you first try an operation:

```python
>>> vault_url = "https://nonexistentvaultdoesnotexist.vault.azure.net"
>>> client = SecretClient(vault_url, DefaultAzureCredential())
>>> client.get_secret('secret_name')
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E313946198>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Failed operations raise errors defined in [azure-core](https://learn.microsoft.com/python/api/azure-core/azure.core.exceptions?view=azure-python) which you can handle as usual with try/except blocks.

Comment: Thank you @CharlesLowell. I will try/except around `get_secret` rather than creation of `SecretClient()`.

Comment: I've opened another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64613699/how-to-add-azure-python-sdk-exceptions-to-try-except-statements); any guidance you have on using `azure core exceptions` would be very beneficial.